# User redirect and authentication with middleware of Nuxt

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to redirect a user to a login page if the user is not logged in when he tries to access certain pages with the following code.

```js
// middlware/authenticated.js
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser   
  store.state.user = user //this doesn't work
  if (!user) {
    console.log('redirect')
    return redirect('/login')   
  }
}
```

However, the problem is with this code when I refresh a page I'm redirected to login page although without using the middleware, I can stay in the same page with logged in. For some reasons, which I don't know why, firebase can't work in middleware.

How should I modify this middleware or implement this function?

Thanks.

```js
//middleware/authenticated.js
export default function ({
  store,
  redirect
}) {
  if (!store.getters['index/isAuthenticated']) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

```js
//post.vue
  async mounted () {
    if (process.browser) {
      let user;
      if (!this.user) user = await auth(); // this auth is a plugin
      await Promise.all([
        this.user ? Promise.resolve() : this.$store.dispatch("setUser", { user: user || null })
      ]);
      this.isLoaded = true;
    }
  },
```

```js
//plugins/auth.js
import firebase from '~/plugins/firebase'

function auth () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      resolve(user || false)
    })
  })
}
export default auth
```

Comment: I had the same problem its because the Middleware already happens Server Side, i will give you some code when im home with a solution but i dont have the code here atm.

Comment: oh that's so helpful! Thank you very much! Ok!

Answer (score 1):

By default Firebase persists the users logged in status on successful authentication. This example uses the session, to store the user uid and cookies to store the users token and used in situations where the sessions has ended (example when browser is closed) and then a new session started but where the user is still authenticated according to Firebase. In cases like these the user will not need to sign in to view protected resources.

Your basic Middleware to protect it should look like this (if you have a Store Module called User)

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.getters['modules/user/isAuthenticated']) {
    return redirect('/auth/signin')
  }
}
```

In [your main Store you use the ServerInit Function](https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-ssr-firebase-auth.v2/blob/master/store/index.js) to get the User if there is one saved in the Cookies and load it into your User Store Module which will be used for verification in the Middleware.

Your User Store Module should look [like this](https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-ssr-firebase-auth.v2/blob/master/store/modules/user.js), and keep in mind that you remove the Cookie when you Log the User out so that he is fully logged out.

I used the things i mentioned above as the beginning of my Authentication and modified it a bit, which you can also do. Most of the credit goes to davidroyer who has set up [this nice Github Repo](https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-ssr-firebase-auth.v2) which includes all needed files as a good example on how to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried your code but still cannot solve the problem. Do I need to implement session and cookies as well? Now I only changed authenticated.js but what's happening right now is I am redirected to a login page when I access a page where I set the middleware(authenticated.js)

Comment: @Masa yes you need to customize redirect to the page that you wanna get thrown to when permissions are missing, well yes i forgot to mention that you need some npm packages like jscookie as you can see in his package.json https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-ssr-firebase-auth.v2/blob/master/package.json , just read through the github repo and look what he did i had some starting problems too but its working if set up right like he did :)

Comment: @Masa just ask me if you get problems

Comment: >>yes you need to customize redirect to the page that you wanna get thrown to when permissions are missing         Really? Oh things seem much more complicated than I expected. But i will try! >>just ask me if you get problems  Thank you!!!

Comment: @Masa overall its not much code im still not home so i cant make you a minified example of what you exactly need but i hope you find your way in, it looks complicated at first but if you got it once it appears simple

Comment: Got it. Thank you~~!

Comment: @Masa Awesome! if you have any more problems with it in the future be sure to ask me :)

Comment: Hi Badgy, long time no see! I finally made it to keep login state on page reload following the example you showed me. Thank you so much! But in this way SSR is necessary as it uses express function... Do you think we can do the same without SSR? It'd be nice if i can deploy it to Netlify..

Comment: @Masa if i remember right if you have a no SSR application then you dont need the server code to check if the user is authenticated, then the basic firebase procedure would be enough for example in the route guard like you would do it in a normal vue page

Comment: yes, but when I tried that, the problem i asked in this page happened... There doesnt seem to be a way to do authentication and route guard with Nuxt without using SSR. On page reload the same problem happens without SSR I guess.

Comment: @Masa Without SSR you can do the Route Guards on the client side, simply with Route Guards, check out the Vue Docs. I also can send you an Vue example. You can use the Route Guards in Nuxt too just read a bit in the internet you will find something.