# Nuxtjs, VUEX and Firebase authentication on page reload

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using Firebase authentication in my Nuxt application, but I can't figure out a good way to persist the user logged-in state in my Store.

I am logging users in by dispatching a async action in my store. when a user refreshes the browser (reloads it), the user will be logged out in my app, but will remain logged in in Firebase (as they didn't log out). It's a problem because the user will have to sign into my app again in order to view restricted pages and perform certain actions.

I tried to grab the user in NuxtServerInit (from the index.js store as I am using modules mode) from:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
```

But it it returns null, and I also tried to listen for:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)
```

But it also returns null

I also tried creating a middleware to check if a user is currently logged in, but it also returns null.

In a previous Vue project I was able to do it in the in the main.js file created-hook like this:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  created () {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        store.dispatch('autoSignIn', user)
      }
    })
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

But I am not able to figure out how to do the same in my Nuxt application.

I appreciate any ideas on how to solve the problem keep my users logged in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696681/user-redirect-and-authentication-with-middleware-of-nuxt/52697814#52697814 here i answered a kind of similar problem i hope my answer there helps you :)

Comment: @Badgy Thank you for sharing that. I looked at the example I can see that I will work for users signing in with Google as the AuthProvider :) I am not sure if the solution is good enough to work with Facebook as Auth Provider too. As far as I know, we don't get a JWT-token from Facebook but an Oauth 2.0 token. any ideas about how to handle Facebook as the AuthProvider?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem following the suggestions shared in the link from @Badgy. Just had to use getIdToken() on the firebase user :)

Comment: awesome, sorry that i didnt answer again but i had a really busy day so I wasnt able to test a solution with Facebook as the Auth provider